# Timeout issue in amazon with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-504

I have a PHP site in which I make an ajax call , in that ajax call I make call to an API that returns XML and I parse it, The problem it sometimes the xML is so huge that it takes many time, The load balancer in EC2 have timeout value of 20 minutes, so If my call is greater than this I get 504 Error, How can I solve this issue? I know its a server issue but how I can solve this?I dont think php.ini is helpful here

Comment: If it takes more than 20 minutes for an HTTP request to respond, you're doing it wrong. Kick off a background task and tell the caller you'll notify them once it's ready, or something like that.

Comment: Have you set into you ajax timeout?

Comment: You can also split up the XML that is returned to the AJAX call

Comment: @jszobody I know my https response is taking more than 20 minutes as I mentioend the XML file is so big, whats new you are telling me?

Comment: @Rico that is not an option here, I wanted to know is there any way to set the timout to unlimited

Comment: @user1765876 I'm saying your application design is bad. If you have to take that long, you shouldn't make the client wait, or timeouts will get you. And you can't extend the ELB timeout beyond 20 minutes. You need to rethink your whole approach.

Comment: @user1765876 I have a long-running task that a browser can request. I kick it off in the background, and then the client has an ajax poll where it checks for an update every few seconds. That would be one approach.

Comment: @sergio no nothing set in ajax

Comment: @jszobody what do you mean "you kick it off in the background" , does that mean ajax? as I am already using it

Comment: @user1765876 No I mean kick off a PHP script in the background, on the server.

Comment: @jszobody ajax is calling a PHP script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. It works best when responses to requests are made within a few seconds of the request. When you don't respond quickly, timeouts start coming into play. This might be a timeout you can control (fcgi process timeout) or one you can't control (third party proxy, client browser).

So what do you do when you have work that will take longer than a few seconds? Use a message queue of course.

The cheap way to do this is store the job in a db table and have cron read from the table and process the work. This can work on a small scale, but it has some issues when you try to get larger.

The proper way to do this is use a real message queue system. Amazon has SQS, but could just as well use Gearman, zeroMQ, rabbitMQ, and others to handle this.

Comment: but how on youtube and other platforms we can upload a video that takes more than 1 hour even, does that mean they are not using http but some other technique like SQS?

Comment: @user1765876 Uploads are a little bit different. There is constant data steaming from the client to the server. With jobs, there is often no data being passed until the job is complete. Timeouts come in to play when no data is being passed.